# How to make React app use env variables from Docker container?

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack

I have a React app that is using env variables specified in webpack.config.js. The issue is that the env variables are hardcoded during build time. How do make it so that the app will use env variables from the Docker container instead? I don't want to keep rebuilding the UI image every single time I want to change an env variable for production.

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'),
      },
    }),
  ],
}
```

Dockerfile

```
# Builder
FROM node:16 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn

COPY src ./src
COPY .babelrc .
COPY webpack* .
COPY config.docker.js ./config.js
COPY tsconfig.json .

RUN yarn build

# Runtime
FROM nginx:1.24-alpine3.17-slim

COPY support/ /
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: This is just how client-side apps work since the runtime environment is the browser. The alternative is to dynamically fetch configuration but that can get complicated quickly